# Connect two source files in python?

Tags: python

I was trying to split [this](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod,_part_13_code) into some smaller files, but its really hard for me becouse of complicated class-global_variable-function relations. Is there any way to connect two files like they were one file in python?

Sorry if this was unclear, i add example of problem:

```
#\a.py
def print_foo():
    global foo
    print foo

#\main.py
from a import *

def initialize_values():
    global foo, bar
    foo='abc'
    bar=123

initialize_values()
print_foo()
```

This causes error "global variable foo not declared" or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried importing?

Comment: This is one reason of many not to use global variables (with very few exceptions).

Comment: importing doesn't work like files were one file. When variable is declared in importing file it cant be used in imported file.

Comment: @TypicalUser Do you mean you can't `import` because some variables share names? There are ways to deal with that.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan that's how I parsed the comment at first too but I believe what he's actually saying is that if b.py imports from a.py, a.py doesn't have access to variables defined in b.py (I.e. importing works differently than just  concatenating two files

Comment: @chucksmash I might be misunderstanding, but what prevents one file importing `a.py` and `b.py`? I may be mistaken, but I believe that should work even if `b.py` also imports `a.py`.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan what prevents are as i said complicated relations of functions, variables and classes.

Comment: @TypicalUser I follow you now. This is a bit of a problem with using `global` which is why it's so discouraged. Unfortunately I don't know how you could resolve this.

Comment: If i knew what i should use instead maybe i could tweak the code i linked to something more multifile-friendly.

Comment: One approach would be to convert globals to explicit parameters to functions (e.g. `create_room` takes two parameters, map and room, instead of just room)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't have truly global variables, only module-level globals. That is, in `a.print_foo`, the statement `global foo` refers to the variable `a.foo`. In `main.initialize_values`, `global foo` refers to `main.foo`. When you call `print_foo`, it tries to print `a.foo`, but that name was never defined.

You could write in `main.py`

```
import a

def initialize_values():
    global bar  # keep in mind, this is main.bar
    a.foo='abc'
    bar=123

initialize_values()
a.print_foo()
```

but that raises a question of design: why are you initializing global variables in the module `a` from a different module?